# Can an acyclic space be determined by its fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be any acyclic CW complex (i.e. reduced homology in all degree is zero). Clearly its fundamental group $\pi_{1}(X)$ is perfect group. Is it true that if $Y$ is any acyclic CW complex with same fundamental group as $X$ then $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think this is true for spaces who are not only acyclic but for which all *twisted cohomology* vanishes as well (I'm not sure but I think this a non-trivial extra assumption). In this case a map $X\to Y$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ exists by obstruction theory (all the obstruction groups vanish by assumption), and since it also induces isomorphisms on all homology groups (twisted or otherwise) it should follow that it is a weak equivalence, and hence a homotopy equivalence by Whitehead's theorem. (I'm not 100% sure about this argument.)

Answer (score 3):

The comment is correct but does not give a very strong result. If $H \subset \pi_1 X$ is a subgroup and $X'$ is the associated cover, the homology $H_*(X; A[\pi_1 X/H]) \cong H_*(X'; A)$. In particular  if $\pi_1 X$ is non-trivial it has a non-trivial cyclic (so Abelian) subgroup $H$, so that $H_1(X'; \Bbb Z) = H$. So any space with $\pi_1 X$ non-trivial has a local coefficient system with non-trivial homology.

The answer to your question itself is no. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/287206) for a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for nice answer.